# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: test.record4

Tags: avro

I am trying to compile an test.avsc avro schema file into java code.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: test.record4

The idea is record4 should be the same type in name4 and name5

My test.avsc is:

```
{

    "type":"record",
    "namespace":"test",
    "name":"record1",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name": "orbject1",
            "type":{
                "type": "array",
                "items":{
                    "type":"record", "name":"record2", "fields": [
                        {"name": "name1",
                            "type":{
                                "type": "array",
                                "items":{
                                    "type":"record", "name":"record3", "fields": [
                                        {"type": {
                                            "type":"record", "name":"record4", "fields": [
                                                {"name":"name2", "type":"long"}
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "name":"name4"
                                        },
                                        {"type": {
                                            "type":"record","name":"test.record4"
                                            },
                                            "name":"name5"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test.record4 error is fixed if you rearrange the schema to look like this:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "namespace":"test",
    "name":"record1",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name": "orbject1",
            "type":{
                "type": "array",
                "items":{
                    "type":"record", "name":"record2", "fields": [
                        {"name": "name1",
                            "type":{
                                "type": "array",
                                "items":{
                                    "type":"record", "name":"record3", "fields": [
                                        {"type": {
                                            "type":"record", "name":"record4", "fields": [
                                                {"name":"name2", "type":"long"}
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "name":"name4"
                                        },
                                        {"type": "test.record4", "name":"name5" }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```